# Generic font in CSS for all texts

Tags: css, font-family

I have a HTML like this:

```
<div id="footer">
    <p> Copyright 2013 </p>
</div>
```

And a CSS like this:

```css
#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #E9E6D9;
}
```

I want my text in `<p>` to have Arial font but I would not like to add the font in the #footer but to make Arial font generic to all texts in the site (which do not have a specific font assigned).

How could I achieve that? I tried adding a `* { font-family:arial; }` but it did not help...

----------------- UPDATE

Here is what I have:

```
body {
font-size: 11px;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,Sans-serif;
color: black;
font-weight: normal;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    width:980px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #E9E6D9;
}
```

But the footer still comes out without inheriting the body's styles... :(

Comment: you are right, the jsfiddle works... Here is my css: http://www.tahara.es/commonItems/TaharaCSS.css do you see anything corrupting the body?

Comment: posting working code with both html and css will help diagnose this, as your html structure isn't apparent from the linked css. Use http://jsfiddle.net/ Also, steering away from using id's to style markup will relieve you of many specificity headaches: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LZz8z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a `style` tag in your css which is invalid.

Removing it resolves the font issue, among others.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZz8z/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Apply that rule to the `body`

```
body {
    font-family: arial;
}
```

Then any other element can override that:

```
.someClass {
    font-family: verdana;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the font on the body, with something like that.

```
body {
    font: 16px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

You will set up, the size, line-height, and font for all font of the site.